# boost::asio::deadline_timer continually triggers

Tags: c++, timer, boost-asio

I've implemented a ios object that calls a handler when the deadline_timer expires.  I'm pretty sure this is done correctly.

pusedo:

```
localScheduler(_localSchedulerIO)

_localSchedulerIO.poll()


while (1)
{
   _localSchedulerIO.reset()
   _localSchedulerIO.poll()
}
```

OK... so this works on i686.   the deadline timer completes every 15 seconds and all is well.

Now for the rub.  When I compile and run on an embedded envrionmment the FIRST time I kick off the program process I get continual "ready" run() handlers.  This is not desireable.  Even weirder.. the SECOND time I run the program is works as expected (15 sec)!  hum..

Anyone know of a dependency that could be satisfied by running the boost::asio once?

dev file missing?

**More Detail: UPDATE:** Would using time_traits derivation help here?

```
Scheduler::Scheduler(ba::io_service& io) :

        ,timer_ (io, seconds(SCHEDULER_TIMER))

{
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&Scheduler::run, this, _1));
}

void Scheduler::run(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{

    if (!error)
    {

    // DO SOMETHING

    // reset timer -- now a run loop

    timer_.expires_at(timer_.expires_at() + seconds(SCHEDULER_TIMER));

    //timer_.expires_at((pt::second_clock::local_time() + seconds(SCHEDULER_TIMER)));

    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&Scheduler::run, this, _1));

    } // timer error
}

Class Scheduler
{
    // timer run 
protected:
    ba::deadline_timer timer_;
}


// main process


MainProcess::MainProcess() :
    , _localScheduler(_localSchedulerIO)
{
}

// scheduler asio
DefaultLogSink().Info("Starting Scheduler server\n");
_localSchedulerIO.run_one();  // blocks until first timer expiry
DefaultLogSink().Info("Scheduler server started\n");


while (1)
{
    _localSchedulerIO.reset();
    _localSchedulerIO.poll_one();  
}
```

Comment: Most likely you've got a race condition or some other UB.

Comment: post the actual code rather than pseudo code. Also, what is the embedded environment?

Comment: I was searching and thought maybe a good idea would be to derive from time_traits, however, I'm still just pulling at straws.  Here is more useful info:

Comment: With the expiration times effectively being offsets instead of absolutes, I'd check if the same behavior occurs with a timer that uses a [monotonic clock](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14848254/1053968), such as [`steady_timer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/steady_timer.html).  Also, it may be worth characterizing the embedded environment's time source.  I've observed various embedded systems where incremental time jumps occur during time calibration on first-use of time.

Comment: Thanks Tanner. I will try that.  The embedded environment (ppc)starts up without an rtc but then uses ntp.

Comment: **Great Suggestion @Tanner Sansbury** This worked as I have above: 'timer_.expires_at(timer_.expires_at() + seconds(SCHEDULER_TIMER));'  Which means if the RTC does not sync, it starts from 1970 and slowing inches forward twards today!  LOL